# Secure Browsing, how

Tags: ubuntu, internet, virtualbox, browsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to browse safely?](https://superuser.com/questions/161065/how-to-browse-safely)

What's the best way to browse "suspicious" sites safely.

I know Firefox used to be "the thing", but now I don't think it is (IMHO).

What I'm using now is a virtual machine (with [virtual box](http://www.virtualbox.org/)), rhat I periodically format.

I heard some time ago of a project that glued the 2 together (kinda... everytime you startup the program it used a fresh machine with a fresh browser), but I lost track of them

So my question is: ***How can I Browse the web securely ?***

Ps.: In in ubuntu

Comment: Very similar to [How to browse safely?](http://superuser.com/questions/161065/how-to-browse-safely)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly if you know a site is unsafe then don't go to it. But if you must use the points below as guidelines.

- With virtual box create a snapshot of
  the machine before browsing the site
  and then revert to the snapshot when
  you are done. This is a bit simpler
  and less time consuming than
  reformatting all the time.
- You could also browse the web with a
  text based browser such as eLinks (
  you can apt-get install elinks).While
  its pretty secure its not the easiest
  way.
- Finally you can do think like
  installing Firefox addin's such as
  NoScript and Block Images. Which
  prevents potentially damaging content
  from loading at all.

Finally there is no real safe way you just have to be careful about where and how you browse